# Launching a file using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, file

I was wondering how I could launch a file using nodejs. Specifically I wanted to be able to run a nodejs file and inside the code, it will open up a certain file on my local hard drive. So I want to know what is the best and safest file way to launch a file or application preferably not using exec?

Thank you

Comment: Have you read the [docs on Process](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/process.html) and [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/child_process.html)?

Comment: Questions like this should show the code you tried and describe a specific problem you encountered that you want help with.  In addition, the little bit of description such as "open up a certain file" is completely unclear what that means.  Do you mean run another program and pass it that file?  Do you mean read the contents of that file in your node.js program?  Or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at the documentation about child process. Here is the link if you would like it:
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/child_process.html